# Initialize an Elasticsearch SearchResponse object before running a query

Tags: elasticsearch, initialization, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I am running various Elastic Search queries from my Java code. In order to consolidate my code, I would like to initialize a SearchResponse object before my conditional loops that each run an ElasticSearch query with different settings. This way, I can execute a single line of code once for getting the total hits from the query. You'll get what I mean from the code

```
@GET
@Path("/search")
public SearchResultsAndFacets search() {
    SearchResultsAndFacets srf = new SearchResultsAndFacets();
    RestHighLevelClient client = createHighLevelRestClient();
    // Build the base query that applies to all searches
    SearchSourceBuilder querySourceBuilder = buildQueryWrapper(colNames, sro.q, sro.f,
                facetsToUpdate, sro.u, sro.lc);
    SearchResponse searchresponse; // This line does not work. How can I initialize this object here (outside of the following conditional loops)?

    // Searches executed from the table view to populate a table of documents
    if (searchType.equals("table")) {
        List<SortParameters> sortParametersList = sortAdapter(sro.s);
        searchResponse = runTableQuery(client, querySourceBuilder, sortParameters, offset, limit);    
    }

    // Searches involving geo_point data to populate a leaflet map
    if (searchType.equals("contacts")) {
        RestHighLevelClient client = createHighLevelRestClient();

        ElasticSearchMapService esms = new ElasticSearchMapService();

        searchResponse = esms.runContactsMapQuery(querySourceBuilder, client, <some geographic coordinate parameters necessary for this search>);

        MapSearchResponse mapSearchResponse = esms.getLocationsFromSearchResponse(searchResponse);
        srf.mapSearchResponse = mapSearchResponse;
    }

// I would like to include these next few lines here at the end of the conditional loops.
// Currently they must be inside each if clause.
    srf.totalHits = searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits().value;
    srf.elapsed = searchResponse.getTook().getMillis();
    srf.facetsData = getUpdatedFacetData(facetsToUpdate,
            searchResponse, sro.f);
    return srf;
}
```

Elastic's high level REST client for JAVA does not allow initializing a SearchResponse object like this. It is also not possible to do so with

> SearchResponse searchResponse = new SearchResponse();

And there is a null pointer error if we do...

> SearchResponse searchResponse = new SearchResponse(null);

How can I rewrite this code so that I can fetech totalHits, elapsed and facetsData outside of the conditional loops?

Comment: As the `SearchResponse` object is an object generated by the HLClient, I don't understand why you would initialize it.

Comment: I added a comments to my code to make the motivation clearer. The goal is to make my code more consise.

Comment: I don't understand why this line `SearchResponse searchresponse;` does not work. That should work...